# How to view discount amount in cart for each product row?

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, discount

Is it possible to show the discount amount for each product row inside the cart? Price rules are set inside the catalog

Answer (score 1):

When editing your cart display view, [you can leverage the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331896/how-to-get-discount-applied-on-cart-line-item-individually) 
 `getDiscountAmount()` method of the `$item` over which you are currently iterating on each row of the cart.  Example usage : `$item->getDiscountAmount();`

You'd need to perform a calculation to derive the actual discount value to display in your cart view, but that could be done by leveraging the `getPrice()` method of the `$item` object also :

`$price = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscountAmount();`

This code may or may not work depending on if you're using Catalog Price Rules to generate the discount vs. Shopping Cart Price Rules.  [As noted here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14647/how-to-get-discounted-price-magento), you have to use Shopping Cart Price rules for this functionality to behave as I've described above.